# How to save a generated pdf in a specific local drive rather than downloads folder when I save

Tags: visualforce, pdf, quote, windows8

I am generating a quote pdf in salesforce using VF.  When I genearate a pdf this should save inside a given directory in local system. I know this is something strange but anybody has a workaround for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Including a link to the same question you asked on the Developer Force boards as it may get different answers: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/How-to-save-a-generated-pdf-in-a-specific-local-drive-rather/td-p/704535

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. A web server can give the browser a clue about the filename of the downloaded PDF using the "Content-disposition" http header. But you can't provide a local folder name this way.

Which makes sense if you think about it. Here we're talking about a web server trying to tell a browser where to store stuff on the user's drive. Not a good idea.